# Lombok @Builder and JPA Default constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I'm using project Lombok together with Spring Data JPA.
Is there any way to connect Lombok `@Builder` with JPA default constructor?

Code:

```
@Entity 
@Builder
class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

As far as I know JPA needs default constructor which is overriden by `@Builder` annotation. Is there any workaround for that?

This code gives me error:
`org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : app.domain.model.Person`

Comment: Try adding a `@NoArgsConstructor` https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/NoArgsConstructor.html

Comment: try adding a no args constructor .AFAIK, `@Builder` will not override your no args constructor

Comment: Yeah but @Id is a required field. NoArgs doesnt gonna cut it

Comment: I don't understand what you want. How can you have a noargs constructor that makes up values? @Id is either required or not. If it is, you need a constructor parameter, if not, you can use NoArgs. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**Updated**

*Based on the feedback and John's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35602246/1331935) I have updated the answer to no longer use `@Tolerate` or `@Data` and instead we create accessors and mutators via `@Getter` and `@Setter`, create the default constructor via `@NoArgsConstructor`, and finally we create the all args constructor that the builder requires via `@AllArgsConstructor`.*

Since you want to use the builder pattern I imagine you want to restrict visibility of the constructor and mutators methods.
To achieve this we set the visibility to `package private` via the `access` attribute on the `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` annotations and the `value` attribute on the `@Setter`annotation.

**Important**

Remember to properly override `toString`, `equals`, and `hashCode`.
See the following posts by Vlad Mihalcea for details:

- [the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
- [how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/)
- [hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/)

```java
package com.stackoverflow.SO34299054;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.junit.Test;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Answer {

    @Entity
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    @Getter
    public static class Person {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        /*
         * IMPORTANT:
         * Set toString, equals, and hashCode as described in these
         * documents:
         * - https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
         * - https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
         * - https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/
         */
    }

    /**
     * Test person builder.
     */
    @Test
    public void testPersonBuilder() {

        final Long expectedId = new Random().nextLong();
        final Person fromBuilder = Person.builder()
            .id(expectedId)
            .build();
        assertEquals(expectedId, fromBuilder.getId());

    }

    /**
     * Test person constructor.
     */
    @Test
    public void testPersonConstructor() {

        final Long expectedId = new Random().nextLong();
        final Person fromNoArgConstructor = new Person();
        fromNoArgConstructor.setId(expectedId);
        assertEquals(expectedId, fromNoArgConstructor.getId());
    }
}
```

**Old Version using `@Tolerate` and `@Data`:**

Using `@Tolerate` worked to allow adding a noarg constructor.

Since you want to use the builder pattern I imagine you want to control visibility of the setter methods.

The `@Data` annotation makes the generated setters `public`, applying `@Setter(value = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)` to the fields makes them `protected`.

Remember to properly override `toString`, `equals`, and `hashCode`.
See the following posts by Vlad Mihalcea for details:

- [the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
- [how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/)
- [hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/)

```java
package lombok.javac.handlers.stackoverflow;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Tolerate;

import org.junit.Test;

public class So34241718 {

    @Builder
    @Data
    public static class Person {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
        Long id;

        @Tolerate
        Person() {}

       /* IMPORTANT:
          Override toString, equals, and hashCode as described in these 
          documents:
          - https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
          - https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
          - https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/
          */
    }

    @Test
    public void testPersonBuilder() {

        Long expectedId = new Random().nextLong();
        final Person fromBuilder = Person.builder()
            .id(expectedId)
            .build();
        assertEquals(expectedId, fromBuilder.getId());

    }

    @Test
    public void testPersonConstructor() {

        Long expectedId = new Random().nextLong();
        final Person fromNoArgConstructor = new Person();
        fromNoArgConstructor .setId(expectedId);
        assertEquals(expectedId, fromNoArgConstructor.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same question as krzakov and I solved it with your hint, using `@Tolerate`. Thanks for that Jeff. But is there any reason why you add the `@Data` annotation? Setters are not necessary in this case and `@Data` overwrites equal/hash/toString with the default behaviour, which can create problems.

Comment: Do not use `@Data` with entities.

Comment: If this is concern is related to toString, equals and hashCode, I have added links to documents regarding proper implementation.

Comment: @wst , why would `@Data` be bad idea with entities?

Comment: @srnjak `@Data` by default uses all fields for generating `equals` and `hashCode` methods, including `id`. Simple example - you may have the same entity representation before and after save which, from Java perspective, will be different instances (with and without an id.) This may lead to confusion and consistency issues. You may use `@Data` if you're overriding those methods. There is chapter of Hibernate docs about it: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode

Comment: @wst, that's reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use `@EqualsAndHashCode (of = {" id "})`?

Comment: That depends on the semantics of the ID field.

If it is a natural identifier/business key (ISBN) or is a database independent generated identifier (UUID) then OK.


Basically it is fine if it matches the database table uniqueness constraint and can be determined and set on the object before it is persisted.

Comment: With the above configuration, self-referencing mapping doesn't work if you use Builder. Not sure if it's a bug or not.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @wollodev wrote earlier, but I wanted to be sure, is setters needed when you now introduced a Builder?

Comment: @wollodev if you want to do updates those must be done via setters not via `toBuilder` since that creates a new disconnected instance.

Answer (score 111):

You can also solve it explicitly with `@Data @Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor` combined on the class definition.

Comment: Note, this does not automatically create accessor methods (getters).

Comment: @Jeff then just add `@Data`

Comment: You don't want to use @Data as this generates equals, hashCode and toString methods, which in the case of jpa entities should be hand generated.  See the details in my answer above.

Answer (score 15):

It seems that the annotations order is important here, using the same annotations, but different orders, you can have the code working, or not.

Here is a non working example:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table
@ToString
public class Person implements Serializable {
  private String name;
}
```

And this is a working example:

```
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table
@ToString
public class Person implements Serializable {
  private String name;
}
```

So be sure to have the @Builder annotation at the very top position, in my case I encountered this error because I wanted to sort annotations alphabetically.

Answer (score 10):

If the annotations *lombok.Tolerate* on constructor and *javax.validation.constraints.NotNull* on some property  are used at the same time, sonarqube will mark it as a critical error: **PROPERTY is marked "javax.validation.constraints.NotNull" but is not initialized in this constructor.**

If the project uses SpringData with JPA, it can be solved using *org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceConstructor* (Spring annotation, not JPA!)

Then, in combination with Lombok, annotations will be like this:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@PersistenceConstructor))
```

For Lombok builder you also need to add:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsContructor` will help solve the issue of having a default constructor with `@Builder`.

e.g

```
@Entity 
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsContructor
class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

This is because `@Builder` requires all argument constructor and specifying only a default constructor will cause an issue.

Here is nore explaination: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1389#issuecomment-369404719

Answer (score 5):

To use the following combination

- lombok
- JPA

  - CRUD
  - proper `@EqualsAndHashCode`
- immutability - public final fields
- no getters
- no setters
- changes via `@Builder` and `@With`

I used:

```
//Lombok & JPA
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241718/lombok-builder-and-jpa-default-constructor

//Mandatory in conjunction with JPA: an equal based on fields is not desired
@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
//Mandatory in conjunction with JPA: force is needed to generate default values for final fields, that will be overriden by JPA
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
//Hides the constructor to force usage of the Builder.
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@lombok.ToString
//Good to just modify some values
@lombok.With
//Mandatory in conjunction with JPA: Some suggest that the Builder should be above Entity - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048267/99248
//Good to be used to modify all values
@lombok.Builder(toBuilder = true)
//final fields needed for imutability, the default access to public - since are final is safe 
@lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
//no getters and setters
@lombok.Getter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
@lombok.Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)

//JPA
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "PERSON_WITH_MOTTO")
//jpa should use field access 
@javax.persistence.Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {
  @javax.persistence.Id
  @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
  //Used also automatically as JPA
  @lombok.EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  Long id;
  String name;
  String motto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i solved this using all these annotations:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeff's answer works fine however, @Builder does not support self-reference relationships yet.

Check this question for more details:

[JPA @OnetoOne self reference relationship with both columns non null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289891/jpa-onetoone-self-reference-relationship-with-both-columns-non-null/61294680#61294680)

Answer (score 0):

`@AllArgsConstructor` required if Builder is used with `@NoArgsConstructor` - because builder needs @`AllArgsConstructor`. - Simple Fix

If you only use @Builder - it will work fine because private parameterized constructor will be created by `@Builder`, but if you use any `XArgsConstructor`, it will override the builder constructor.

So if you use, `@Builder` and `@NoArgsConstructor` or default constructor, then `NoArgsConstructor` will override the Builder's parameterized constructor.

That is the reason you will get error like:

> required: no arguments found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Because your `@NoArgsConstructor` was expecting no arguments, but builder is trying to use same by passing parameters.