# How to have lombok to create constructor for non null fields since @RequiredArgsConstructor seems not to work?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, lombok

I am playing with the **Lombok** and already went through many link but none of them worked for me.

**Person.java**

```
@Setter @Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String lastName;
}
```

PersonController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        personRepository.save(new Person(person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName()));  //line-34
    }
}
```

But its not allowing me to create the two argument constructor

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The constructor Person(String, String) is undefined
    - The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Person,Long> is not applicable for the arguments 
     (Person)
```

**On line No-34 its breaking...**

**EDIT-1:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void updatePerson(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Person person) {
        Person existingPerson = personRepository.findOne(id);
        existingPerson.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
        existingPerson.setLastName(person.getLastName());
        personRepository.save(existingPerson);
    }
```

Here is the error

```
The method setFirstName(String) is undefined for the type Person
```

The changes I made

```
@Setter @Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor()
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private final String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private final String lastName;
}
```

-===================

**Edit-2**

Here is the final result:

```
@Setter @Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using @EqualsAndHashCode on JPA entities. Read the links in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299054/1331935

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have Lomboks `@NonNull` annotation on those fields. I noticed it just now.

You have only `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` annotation on those fieldṣ and `@RequiredArsgConstructor` does not apply on that.

Add the `@NonNull` in addition to the `@NotNull` annotation. It might be that you do not need the `@NotNull` anymore so try to remove it  also.

```
@NonNull 
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
private String firstName;

@NonNull 
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
private String lastName;
```

Comment: But its breaking my other code shown above in edit. Please show the code snippet, so that I can understand.

Comment: Then what would be the solution ? Looks like Lombok approach will not suffice for the Jpa and mongo

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, i read the lombok docs again and saw the actual problem.

Comment: Hey, I dont understand your last comment. What do I need to change in that model class ? Please guide