# Add default public constructor to generated builder inner class

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I am using Lombok framework for boilerplate code generation, for example:

```
import lombok.*;


@Builder
@Value
public final class SocketConfig {

    @Builder.Default
    private int soTimeoutMilliseconds = 0;

    @Builder.Default
    private boolean soReuseAddress = false;

    @Builder.Default
    private int soLingerSeconds = -1;

    private boolean soKeepAlive;

    @Builder.Default
    private boolean tcpNoDelay = false;

}
```

In order to create builder instances I used to invoke `SocketConfig.builder()`. But for better integration with spring beans creation I tried to create a `FactoryBean`. But got a compilation error due to lack of default constructor on the builder class, didn't find any documentation about it. Is it possible with Lombok? I mean to create a default constructor on the builder not on the original class. In other words, I want 2 options to create the builder instance: `SocketConfig.builder()` or through `new SocketConfig.SocketConfigBuilder()`.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;

public class SocketConfigFactoryBean extends SocketConfig.SocketConfigBuilder implements FactoryBean<SocketConfig> {



    @Override
    public SocketConfig getObject() throws Exception {
        return build();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return SocketConfig.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lombok @Builder and JPA Default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241718/lombok-builder-and-jpa-default-constructor)

Comment: Don't extend `SocketConfig.SocketConfigBuilder` just encapsulate it.

Comment: In this case I will need to maintain all fields names in the current class as well.

Comment: No you don't. Create a `builder` inside the factory and simply expose setters for the properties which directly set the values on the encapsulated builder.

Answer (score 1):

Use the annotation [`NoArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/NoArgsConstructor.html):

> Generates a no-args constructor. Will generate an error message if
>   such a constructor cannot be written due to the existence of final
>   fields.

[Read also this.](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)

Comment: This will generate a constructor on the original class not on the inner builder class.

Comment: Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35602246/2436655) might help you. Thanks to @MaximKirilov for his comment.

Comment: It doesn't, it will generate 2 constructors on the constructed class. I want 2 options to create the builder instance: "SocketConfig.builder()" or through "new SocketConfig.SocketConfigBuilder()"